# Merging python lists based on a 'similar' float value

Tags: python, list

I have a list (containing tuples) and I want to merge the list based on if the first element is within a maximum distance of the other elements (if if delta value < 0.05). I have the following list as an example:

```
[(0.0, 0.9811758192941256), (1.00422, 0.9998252466431066), (0.0, 0.9024831978342827), (2.00425, 0.9951777494430947)]
```

This should yield something like:

```
[(0.0, 1.883659017),(1.00422, 0.9998252466431066),(2.00425,0.9951777494430947)]
```

I am thinking that I can use something similar as in this question ([Merge nested list items based on a repeating value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17286252/1093485)) altho a lot of other questions yield a similar answer. The only problem that I see there is that they use `collections.defaultdict` or `itertools.groupby` which require exact matching of the element. An important addition here is that I want the first element of a merged tuple to be the weighted mixture of elements, example as follows:

`(1.001,80)` and `(0.99,20)` are matched then the result should be `(0.9988,100)`.

Is something similar possible but with the matching based on value difference and not exact match?

What I was trying myself (but don't really like the look of it) is:

```
Res = 0.05
combinations = itertools.combination(list,2)
for i in combinations:
  if i[0][0] > i[1][0]-Res and i[0][0] < i[1][0]+Res:
    newValue = ...
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Based on some comments and Dawgs answer I tried the following approach:

```
for fv, v in total:
    k=round(fv, 2)
    data[k]=data.get(k, 0)+v
```

using the following list (actual data example, instead of short example list):

```
total = [(0.0, 0.11630591852564721), (1.00335, 0.25158664272201053), (2.0067, 0.2707487305913156), (3.0100499999999997, 0.19327075057473678), (4.0134, 0.10295042331357719), (5.01675, 0.04364856520231155), (6.020099999999999, 0.015342958201863783), (0.0, 0.9811758192941256), (1.00422, 0.018649427348981), (0.0, 0.9024831978342827), (2.00425, 0.09269455160881204), (0.0, 0.6944298762418107), (0.99703, 0.2536959281304138), (1.99406, 0.045877927988415786)]
```

which then yields problems with values such as 2.0067 (rounded to 2.01) and 1.99406 (rounded to 1.99( where the total difference is 0.01264 (which is far below 0.05, a value that I had in mind as a 'limit' for now but that should set changeable). Rounding the values to 1 decimal place is also not an option since that would result in a window of ~0.09 with values such as `2.04999` and `1.95001` which both yield 2.0 in that case.

The exact output was:

```
{0.0: 2.694394811895866, 1.0: 0.5239319982014053, 4.01: 0.10295042331357719, 5.02: 0.04364856520231155, 2.0: 0.09269455160881204, 1.99: 0.045877927988415786, 3.01: 0.19327075057473678, 6.02: 0.015342958201863783, 2.01: 0.2707487305913156}
```

Comment: You could round the values to whatever precision you like and then use the exact-match algorithm.

Comment: @tobias_k I can't, I need the exact values in case (in the future) the instrument that we measure on is capable of differentiating these values. That is why I want to use the `Res` (short for resolution) value to get a 'pooled' distribution while still being able to output the exact distribution (that can not be differentiated on the machine) to compare theoretical and observed distributions.

Comment: You could keep the original values, just use the rounded value as the key for grouping. However, there's a problem if, say, one value is `0.49` and the other is `0.51`, they would be rounded in opposite directions...

Comment: Another question: Lets say epsilon is `0.1` and you have value `0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4`. How should those be grouped?

Comment: I am assuming that your epsilon refers to the maximum distance between values, correct? All values in each list are roughly ~1.0 away (exact distance is based on the elements isotopic mass difference) so the problem that you point at (would 0.25 goto 0.2 or 0.3) is not present. I was however going to weigh the mass (first element in each tuple) based on the fraction (second value in each tuple) to correct for the different isotopic masses.

Comment: Concerning your Update: If you want a 'limit' of `0.05`, you have to round to _one_ decimal place, this will then round `2.0067` and `1.99406` both to `2.0`

Comment: The limit would be maximum of ~0.09 if we round to 1 decimal since both 1.95001 and 2.04999 would be rounded to 2.0.

Comment: @BenJansen In an earlier comment you said that you actually want _whole_ numbers in your result list, or that the actual difference between the real values is about 1.0, so where does that limit of 0.05 come from in the first place? Is it just so that you can not use `round`, because that would either round to `0.01` or `0.1`?

Comment: The limit of 0.05 was listed in the code snippet that is in the OP with what I was trying myself (with the `itertools.combinations` option) and I referred back to it in my first comment here. I am not sure where I mentioned that I want whole numbers in my list?

Comment: I think I get what you refer to know with the whole numbers. I stated that each difference is roughly ~1.0 (the differences are either 1.004, 1.003 or 0.994 based on the exact element) which for small chemicals (a limited amount of these values) means that you could get away with seeing them as whole numbers but if we move to large chemicals you could get a complete distribution (with unique values anywhere in between for instance 4000.0 and 4001.0). I hope that clears it up a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
accum = list()
data = [(0.0, 0.9811758192941256), (1.00422, 0.9998252466431066), (0.0, 0.9024831978342827), (2.00425, 0.9951777494430947)]

EPSILON = 0.05

newdata = {d: True for d in data}
for k, v in data:
    if not newdata[(k,v)]: continue
    newdata[(k,v)] = False
    # use each piece of data only once
    keys,values = [k*v],[v]
    for kk, vv in [d for d in data if newdata[d]]:
        if abs(k-kk) < EPSILON:
            keys.append(kk*vv)
            values.append(vv)
            newdata[(kk,vv)] = False
    accum.append((sum(keys)/sum(values),sum(values)))
```

Comment: as a side note, my variable naming needs work in this but since I don't know what any of these actually symbolize...

Comment: The tuples represent (delta mass, total fraction) but I am going to have a look at this option and try it. You are missing a `:` in your `for k,v in data` line ;)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you do with the `if not newdata[d]: continue` line in relation to `newdata = {d: True for d in data}`, the snippet as is yields an `NameError` as well since `d` is not defined.

Comment: @BasJansen yeah I made a number of typos when I was trying to wrap my head around the problem and didn't have time to test it. Done so now.

Comment: I changed the `sum(keys)/100` part into `sum(keys)/sum(values)` to get the actual weighing I wanted and now it's exactly what I was trying to do myself, cheers.

Comment: @BasJansen oops, I misunderstood your example in a comment on dawg's answer as to how your weighting should run. I've edited my answer so that it's correct.

Comment: @BasJansen For what it's worth, if you can set some kind of sane rounding rules for yourself then dawg's answer is MASSIVELY faster. For any datatable of moderate size, my approach is going to bring your computer to a standstill.

Comment: Fair point, I am intending to actually bench this approach today on some cohort datasets.

Comment: +1 from me -- May I suggest constructing the dict keys as tuples showing upper and lower values that define the sums represented? i.e., `{(2.00, 2.25)=2.121.....}` so that the bounds of the rounding are easily seen by inspection

Answer (score 2):

You can round the float values then use setdefault:

```
li=[(0.0, 0.9811758192941256), (1.00422, 0.9998252466431066), (0.0, 0.9024831978342827), (2.00425, 0.9951777494430947)]

data={}
for fv, v in li:
    k=round(fv, 5)
    data.setdefault(k, 0)
    data[k]+=v

print data
# {0.0: 1.8836590171284082, 2.00425: 0.9951777494430947, 1.00422: 0.9998252466431066}
```

If you want some more complex comparison (other than fixed rounding) you can create a hashable object based on the epsilon value you want and use the same method from there.

---

As pointed out in the comments, this works too:

```
data={}
for fv, v in li:
    k=round(fv, 5)
    data[k]=data.get(k, 0)+v
```

Comment: why not just use `get`? `data[k] = data.get(k, 0) + v`

Comment: @AdamSmith: Better still!

Comment: I want to say that the comparison has to be a bit more complex altho I don't have any example ready on the top of my head. The handling of the matched data is a bit more complex but that is easy to deal with and implies that the first element of the list must change based on the second element of the list (I should have added that more clearly to the OP), but for instance if (1.001, 80) and (0.99,20) are matched than the result should be ((1.001*80)+(0.99*20)/100),80+20) -> (0.9988,100).

Comment: @BasJansen please edit that into the question -- it doesn't invalidate this approach though (`fv` is still your original first element without rounding)

Comment: @AdamSmith I just did that and edited my comment since it is as you say. I am still thinking about the answer however as I just have the feeling that I'd be missing something using the rounding method.

Comment: @BasJansen the round is only to apply your "fuzzy" matching. There's certainly no faster way to do it than this, and you're applying your actual float to the data. I'll try and work up something that works better for your purpose, however.

Comment: I just found a problem with this option which I will include in the OP.